# Error: Please install Android target 19 (the Android newest SDK) on windows 7 while creating phonegap project

Tags: android

please help me to get out from this error.

I have installed android target 19 and it is showing on SDK manager. But still am getting this error.

Error: Please install Android target 19 (the Android newest SDK). Make sure you
have the latest Android tools installed as well. Run "android" from your command
-line to install/update any missing SDKs or tools.

The Path is:

```
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32
\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin;E:\phoneGap
\phoneGap19052014\cordova-3.4.0\cordova-android\bin;E:\phoneGap\phoneGap19052014
\apache-ant-1.9.0\bin;E:\phoneGap\phoneGap19052014\adt-bundle-windows-x86-201307
29\sdk\platform-tools;E:\phoneGap\phoneGap19052014\adt-bundle-windows-x86-201307
29\sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Users\la263572\AppData\Roaming\np
m
```

Comment: can you show the manifest file

Comment: @devil Abhi : While creating the project itself it is giving error.From where it is come manifest file!!

Answer (score 3):

```
Finally the way I fixed the problem on my system (Windows 8, 64 bit, JDK 7) was:

1.Create JAVA_HOME environment variable and point it to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin
2.Open ANDROID SDK DIRECTORY\tools\android.bat in your favourite text editor
3.Find the lines set java_exe= call lib\find_java.bat (it's split over 2 lines)
4.Replace the lines with set java_exe="%JAVA_HOME%\java.exe"
5.Save and run tools\android.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

create new android application project and try to set its target sdk to 19
and if there is no option of sdk19 then Download the latest version of ADT, and respond me whatever is...

[image]

Comment: @abhi : am creating project through command prompt.E:\>cd phoneGap\phoneGap19052014\cordova-3.4.0\cordova-android\bin

E:\phoneGap\phoneGap19052014\cordova-3.4.0\cordova-android\bin>create com.xyz.SamApp